# Google Datastore error: No matching index found

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to test a new Entity I created in the Google Datastore. I'm trying to do a GQL Query with an inequality to retrieve some entities in the datastore web interface:

> SELECT * FROM UserMatchingIndex WHERE age < 25 AND wants_male = false AND wants_dating = false AND wants_friendship = false AND wants_age = 20

But I always have an error : "GQL query error: Your Datastore does not have the composite index (developer-supplied) required for this query." whereas I have defined the required composite indexes !

> UserMatchingIndex: age ▲ wants_male ▲ wants_dating ▲ wants_friendship ▲     wants_age ▲ Serving
>
> UserMatchingIndex: age ▲ wants_female ▲ wants_dating ▲ wants_friendship ▲     wants_age ▲ Serving

These are defined as followed in the index.yaml:

```
- kind: UserMatchingIndex
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: age
  - name: wants_male
  - name: wants_dating
  - name: wants_friendship
  - name: wants_age

- kind: UserMatchingIndex
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: age
  - name: wants_female
  - name: wants_dating
  - name: wants_friendship
  - name: wants_age
```

I really don't see what could be possibly wrong... I've done that many times for other entities. If you have some clues, you're welcome.

Comment: Do these indexes have a "Serving" status in the dev console?

Comment: Yes, they have "Serving" status as you can see above.

Comment: Normally the error in the log suggests what index should be added. At least that's what it does if you'd use UserMatchingIndex.query().filter(UserMatchingIndex.wants_male == False, UserMatchingIndex.wants_dating == False, UserMatchingIndex.wants_friendship == False, UserMatchingIndex.wants_age == 20, UserMatchingIndex.age < 25)

Comment: I'm using PHP App Engine, I don't have any more info than "No matching index found" as an error.

Comment: Have you tried running the query in the Cloud Console?

Comment: I already tried as mentioned above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue was submitted to Google Cloud support and it seems to be an issue on their side, or at least, a restriction not documented yet. Changing the order of the properties as followed:

```
- kind: UserMatchingIndex
  ancestor: no
  properties:
  - name: wants_male
  - name: wants_dating
  - name: wants_friendship
  - name: wants_age
  - name: age
```

makes the query work.

**EDIT: Answer from Google Support**

> "The rows of an index table are sorted first by ancestor and then by property values, in the order specified in the index definition. The perfect index for a query, which allows the query to be executed most efficiently, is defined on the following properties, in order:
>
> 1. Properties used in equality filters
> 2. Property used in an inequality filter (of which there can be no more than one)
> 3. Properties used in sort orders
>
> This ensures that all results for every possible execution of the query appear in consecutive rows of the table."

This restriction should be documented soon.